# How to recover from swap files correctly on Neovim?

Tags: neovim, swap-file

My Mac crashed and was forced to restart. So I opened Terminal, try recovering the file, but struggle to correctly recover the file.

Specifically, I tried the following command:

```
nvim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

Then it popped up the following error:

> Swap file "~/.local/share/nvim/swap//%Users%me%.config%nvim%init.vim.swp" already exists!
>
> [O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:

I chose R (by typing in `R`), but then got the following message:

> E305: No swap file found for /Users/me/.config/nvim/init.vim

But in `~/.local/share/nvim/swap`, there is certainly the swap file, and I wonder why I get the error message above.

Is this a bug or what am I missing here?

Comment: report as bug to the neovim guys then

Comment: Have you modified the buffer? From `:h e305`: "The current contents of the buffer are lost. This command fails if the buffer was modified."